# Why do we have momenta $k_\pm=k_x \pm i k_y$ in $k\cdot p$ models instead of $k$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, notation, perturbation-theory

The [Hamiltonian](https://badihassaf.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/lecture-15.pdf) for a simple 2-band model after $k\cdot p$ is:

$H(k)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{E}{2}+\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} & \frac{\hbar}{m}k\cdot P \\
\frac{\hbar}{m}k\cdot P & -\frac{E}{2}+\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}
\end{bmatrix},$

where $P=\langle u_n | H_k | u_m \rangle$.

In 2D, one may use $k=\sqrt{k_{x}^2+k_{y}^2}$.

In most condensed matter works, however, authors instead use the notation
$q_\pm=q_x\pm i \nu q_y$ instead, where $\nu=\pm 1$ is the valley index. They also typically introduce
a $\phi=\text{atan}\left(\frac{q_{y}}{q_{x}}\right)$ variable.
This notation is seen after Eq. 4f of [this reference](https://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/burkard/sites/default/files/images/2053-1583_2_2_022001.pdf), for example.

Why do they do this? I am guessing circular polarization is somehow involved based on the notation $\pm i$, but I don't understand how this falls into context with the Hamiltonian given above. That is, will I now have two Hamiltonians (one with $k \rightarrow q_x$ and the other with $k \rightarrow q_y$)?
Or is there some other minimal $k\cdot p$ Hamiltonian $H(q_\pm)$ that I can use to understand this instead of the $H(k)$ version given above?

I understand that different material systems will call for different matrix elements, but surely there is a simple, general version such as $H(k)$ above for $H(q_\pm)$ that elucidates the role of $q_\pm$ better? I have not found any in the literature so far, but I am missing something fundamental and basic here.

Comment: Okay, it looks like that might come from wavefunctions and eigenvalues of specific systems? I found these notes that make it seem that way: https://badihassaf.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/lecture-17-presentation.pdf